# Make .Net Web API JSON output pretty

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api

I'm using code below to get data in JSON format using Newtonsoft.Json:

my code to create the JSON is

```
            Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
            Dim sw As New StringWriter(sb)
            Dim writer As JsonWriter = New JsonTextWriter(sw)  
            writer.WriteStartArray()

            For Each elements As JToken In result
                If i = 0 Then
                    i += 1
                    Continue For
                End If
                For Each aaa As JToken In elements
                    writer.WriteStartObject()
                    Dim pmid = aaa("uid").Value(Of String)
                    Dim issn = aaa("issn").Value(Of String)
                    Dim essn = aaa("essn").Value(Of String)
                    Dim source = aaa("source").Value(Of String)                 
                    Dim sortpubdate = aaa("sortpubdate").Value(Of String)

                    writer.WritePropertyName("pmid")
                    writer.WriteValue(pmid)
                    writer.WritePropertyName("journal")
                    writer.WriteValue(source)

                    writer.WritePropertyName("issn")
                    writer.WriteValue(issn)
                    writer.WritePropertyName("essn")
                    writer.WriteValue(essn)
                    writer.WritePropertyName("sortpubdate")
                    writer.WriteValue(sortpubdate)
                    writer.WritePropertyName("pubYear")  
                    writer.WriteEndObject()
                Next
            Next
            writer.Close()
            Return sb.ToString
```

and the output code is

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get()
{
    string yourJson = GetJsonFromSomewhere();
    var response = this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    response.Content = new StringContent(yourJson, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    return response;
}
```

My current output is.

```
[{"pmid":"29241721","issn":"0749-3797","essn":"1873-2607","journal":"Am J Prev Med","pubYear":"2018","ImpactFactor":"  4.127"},{"pmid":"28987617","issn":"0166-4328","essn":"1872-7549","journal":"Behav Brain Res","pubYear":"2018","ImpactFactor":"  3.173"},
```

Is there a way I can indent my output?

```
[{
    "pmid": "29241721",
    "issn": "0749-3797",
    "essn": "1873-2607",
    "journal": "Am J Prev Med",
    "pubYear": "2018",
    "ImpactFactor": "  4.127"
}, {
```

Is there a way I can do it like below?

```
this.SerializerSettings.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
```

The client side is just a simple browser URL that get a response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got what I needed with

```
    Dim writer As JsonWriter = New JsonTextWriter(sw)
    writer.Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented
```

Answer (score 0):

You should indent your object in serialization time and then use it everywhere you want. If `GetJsonFormatSomewhere()` is your serialization method you should seralize your object in that method below:

```
var serializedObject = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data, Formatting.Indented);
```

and then pass indented object to `StringContent` method.

**Note:** it's better to indent your output in client side, that way your packet size will stay small and it's performance friendly.

Comment: I agree with your comment but I also need a raw response that is for more proof of concept to administrators that can be easier read/displayed and not to be added to Client code.